# PATH is not properly set up ZSH

Tags: rvm, zsh

So I installed rvm, however after I source my .zshrc I always get a warning

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/kimchi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.1'.
```

And then zsh is crashing

However as far as I see it *is* in the first place...

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/kimchi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/kimchi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/Users/kimchi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/kimchi/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin:/Users/kimchi/.go/bin:/Users/kimchi/bin:/Users/kimchi/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/m-cli:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/kimchi/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/opt/fzf/bin
```

here are my .zshrc paths

```
typeset -U path

path=(
    $HOME/.rvm/bin
    $GOROOT/bin
    $GOPATH/bin
    $HOME/bin
    $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
    /usr/local/{bin,sbin}
    /usr/bin
    /usr/local/git/bin
    /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
    $path
)
```

also added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

to the bottom...

Comment: I doubt `zsh` is crashing; whatever is checking your path seems to be unnecessarily exiting the shell.